# Python subprocess.call module is throwing a 500 internal server error

Tags: python, subprocess, cgi

I have the following two lines

```
call(["./convertToPDF.sh"], shell=False)
print "Location: output.pdf"
```

The script generates the pdf, however it produces a 500 Internal Server Error instead of redirecting. If the line is removed from the file it works fine, except for the fact that the pdf is not generated. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the server error logs.

Comment: What line are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the call line.

Comment: it seems unlikely that the relative path works. Also, to terminate the headers, you need additional newline: `print`. Configure the cgi script so that you would see the errors (`sys.stderr` and include `cgitb.enable()` for debugging) and use `check_call('/absolute/path/to/generate-pdf', stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True)` where `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`